# Как организовать модальное окно ведомления на рабочий стол?

Tags: php, javascript

Лазая по просторам сети наткнулся на сайт *101.ru* (и не только на него). При заходе появилось такое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь понять это просто развод и кука или что то что действительно позволяет получать новости на рабочий стол. Если это второе - не подскажите как и что это? И возможно ли такое организовать средствами *javascript* и *PHP*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае будут включено уведомление в браузере.
Вы будете получать всплывающие уведомления в браузере, где будет заголовок, текст и адрес сайта.

[Push API and Notification API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web)

Comment: Это для каждого браузера отдельно для огненной лисы есть ?

Comment: Поддерживает chrome, firefox, Safari частично. Пример кода посмотрите — https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo